# merge two node_modules folders having separate package.json files

Tags: node.js, docker, dockerfile, node-modules, npm-install

I am trying to install multiple package.json files in the same node_module folder. The reason behind separate package.json is I am using docker and I have some private modules which change frequently. Due to this, the docker reinstalls all modules whenever I build the image. It is time-consuming and also a waste of internet usage.

To overcome this issue, I have created separate private-package.json for my private modules.

```
COPY package.json package.json
RUN npm i
COPY private-package.json package.json
RUN npm i
CMD ["npm", "start" ]
```

But whenever I install this private-package.json, it replaces all old modules installed by package.json and if I see there are only those modules available in the node_modules folder which are installed using my private-package.json.

To overcome this, I used rsync as per the below approach,

```
COPY package.json package.json
RUN npm i && mv node_modules another_folder/
COPY private-package.json package.json
RUN npm i && rsync another_folder/node_modules node_modules
CMD ["npm", "start" ]
```

This solves my problem but is it the correct approach? OR is there any way form that will install in the same folder in node_modules? Can you please help me?

Thanks

Comment: Docker should be able to use the layer cache to avoid repeating `RUN rpm i` if the `package*.json` files haven't changed.  I don't see an obvious advantage to splitting this up the way you're showing.  (...unless the "private" package dependencies change very frequently.)

Comment: Thanks for your reply @David Maze. But my private modules are used in multiple projects. So if I update these modules, I need to build all images once again to use these in the project. Some of them having node-modules with size 1 to 1.5 GB. This takes more time to install if the network is slow.